# implementing stack with a linked list in C++ , copy constructor

Tags: c++, stack, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a stack using a linked list in C++, and I don't know how to write correctly the copy constructor of the stack class.

I am using the following classes:

```
class Node{
    int m_num;
    Node* m_pNext;
public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    //and the standard get&set functions..
}


class LinkedList{
    int m_size;
    Node* m_pHead;
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& obj);
    ~LinkedList();
    //and the standard get&set functions..
}


class Stack{
    LinkedList m_stack;
public:
    Stack();
    Stack(const Stack& copyStack);
    ~Stack();
}
```

I did wrote the copy constructor of the LinkedList class, and it is working well.
My problem is with the Stack class, there I cant get a copy of my current stack in order to search in the stack (involves pop() and so on).

I did try to write the following:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack &copyStack){
    LinkedList m_stack = copyStack.m_stack;
}
```

and as I said, it doesnt work..

I am new to C++, and I guess I am missing something there..

Comment: If `LinkedList` is correctly copyable, then you don't need to provide a copy-constructor for `Stack`; the implicit one will do the right thing. http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero

Comment: But don't forget the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) for `LinkedList`: it seems to be missing a copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this to learn C++ as you should be using it for normal programming, consider taking a different route (e.g. try creating a simple program, not a data structure). That's because C++ already has standard library implementations for most things you'd use here, such as a pointer automatically managing memory deallocation (`std::unique_ptr`), a linked list (`std::forward_list` and `std::list`), and even a stack (`std::stack`).

To learn the language, you should learn using these first, before you dive into how they can be implemented.

---

If, on the other hand, you're doing this to learn about data structures and memory management (and C++ is just a tool in this regard), go ahead. But you'd be better off if you knew the language better before you dive into such low-level tasks.

Nevertheless, there are two problems in your code. One is that you declare a new local variable instead of assigning to a member. You probably meant this:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack &copyStack){
    m_stack = copyStack.m_stack;
}
```

Second, this requires `LinkedList` to implement an appropriate copy assignment operator. Without this, the default-generated one will be used, which simply copies all members. That would result in a shallow copy only - both the newly constructed stack object and the original `copyStack` would point to the same nodes inside their `LinkedList` - probably not what you want.

Still, a better way to do this would be to *initialise* `m_stack` with the appropriate value; what you're doing now initialises `m_stack` to empty and then assings into it. You should change the copy constructor to use a member-initialiser-list:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack &copyStack) : m_stack(copyStack.m_stack)
{}
```

This will call the copy constructor of `LinkedList`, and not the assignment operator.

Still, any class which manages resources (actually any C++ class) must follow the ["Rule of Three"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1782465) to work correctly. That rule states that if a class has a custom copy constructor, custom copy assignment operator or custom destructor, it should define all 3 of those to work correctly. `LinkedList` has a copy constructor and a destructor, which means you should also provide a copy assignment operator, e.g. like this:

```
LinkedList& operator= (const LinkedList &src);
```

I will leave its implementation as an excercise for the reader ;-) You can also look up the "copy and swap" idiom.

Once you do that, you should actually *remove* the copy constructor (and probably destructor too) from `Stack`, as the default-generated one will do just what you need - call the copy constructor on each member.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler-generated copy constructor would work.

If you really want to implement it manually, then:

```
Stack(const Stack& copyStack) : m_stack(copyStack.m_stack) {}
```

Note that you should use the constructor initialization list. Then `m_stack` is created by using `LinkedList`'s copy-constructor.

Of course, this relies on the fact that you must have implemented `LinkedList(const LinkedList& obj);` correctly!

Comment: BTW, using `m_stack` for the name of a `LinkedList`, when you also have a `Stack` type, is confusing!

Comment: Yeah, I know, it confused me to.. but I was told to do so.. :/  
and Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You create a local variable called `m_stack`. This masks the member variable `m_stack`. You need to remove the `LinkedList`:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack &copyStack){
    m_stack = copyStack.m_stack;
}
```

Further more you also need a copy assignment operator (`operator=`) that copies the members. You defined a copy constructor, so you need to think about the "Rule of Three" for c++

Comment: This requires `Stack` to implement `operator=`, which it currently doesn't.

Comment: Also known as the copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is already part of the language:

```
#include <stack>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::stack<int, std::list<int>> my_stack;
}
```

Comment: I would always recommend this over any self-made implementation.

Comment: self-implementation of simple data structures can be a good exercise for learning the language

Comment: OTOH, getting familiar with standard containers usually improves a beginner's interface-design skills.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wouldn't say so. That tends to produce programmers who do everything by hand (memory management, algorithms, data structures) instead of relying on the tried&tested things in the standard library. Once you're learned the language and `std`, sure, go learn the low-level stuff, but it's not the best starting point.

Comment: Doing it yourself gives you an appreciation of what the standard versions do..:)  There's no single "best" starting point, and I would dispute the assertion that it encourages bad programming habits. Knowing how something works is never bad. I'm not suggesting they ban themselves from learning standard containers or anything.